# How to get the data with maximum id

Tags: sql, oracle

I need the data which just have maximum `instrn_id` with all rows, max I can't use as t returns only one row:

```
instrn_id ordr_id

599999  1659
599999  1659
599999  1659
599998  1633
599998  1633
599998  1633
599660  1659
599659  1633
599321  1659
599321  1659
599321  1659
599320  1633
599320  1633
599320  1633
598979  1659
598978  1633
598638  1659
598638  1659
598638  1659
598637  1633
598637  1633
```

Comment: can you post your expected output ?

Comment: First you select the maximum id using the MAX function, than you select all the rows that have their ID equal with the maximum ID that you just selected

Answer (score 4):

Could be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM _yourtable_
WHERE instr_id = (SELECT MAX(instr_id) from _yourtable_)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
_yourtable_ t1
JOIN
(SELECT MAX(instr_id) m FROM _yourtable_) t2
ON t1.instr_id  = m
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work in mssql. I think oracle has the same syntax:

```
;with x as
(
select *, rank() over (order by ordr_id desc) rnk 
from <table>
) 
select instrn_id, ordr_id
from x
where rnk = 1
```